# Gradle Issue with Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have been facing a particular kind of problem while building my project since the installation of new Android studio 2.2. The issue seems to be of gradle. I am attaching [image: the image here]. It has something to do with the `InternalBuildActionAdapter`. I could not find anything related to that. When I try the redownload option provided in the error, it doesn't work. I have no idea what needs to be done. I had a separate installation of android studio for canary and when I tried to open this project with that, it opens and runs perfectly fine. Is there something wrong with this android 2.2 version? What is the fix?

This project uses the following gradle classpath `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0`

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: This project uses the following gradle classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0

Comment: I'm asking about the version of Gradle, not the plugin. Open the Terminal and type `./gradlew -version`.

Comment: Sorry, I am using 2.14.1...